# TYPO3 tt_address email limit

Tags: typo3

I use a tt_address ext to display addresses on website.
Is it possible to display more than one email address from email field? I would like to insert into tt_address email field two or three emails, separate them by `,` (comma) and display all addresses in separate `a` element.

I have that TS who split the addresses but activate only first email address to all:

```
email{
    field = email
    split{
        token = ,
        cObjNum = 1
        1.current = 1
        1.typolink.parameter.field = email
        1.typolink.ATagParams = class="email"

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 1.typolink.parameter.field = email, you would insert your whole email field (test@example.com,test2@example.com). So i guess using current=1 instead should solve the issue. *untested*

```
email{
    field = email
    split{
        token = ,
        cObjNum = 1
        1.current = 1
        1.typolink.parameter.current = 1
        1.typolink.ATagParams = class="email"

    }
}
```